# Is there a way to query a pickle dataset using something like where

Tags: python, pickle

Consider I have an object with 3 properties (viz. Name, Size, Type). I have 1000 such objects pickled and store in a file. Is it possible to load the dataset and then query it for the particular object with name 'Main'.

Currently, I am doing the following, but I hope so there is much effective way:

```
with open(pickle_dataset_path, "rb") as file:
    content = pickle.load(file)

for obj in content:
    if obj.name == 'Main':
        return obj
```

So if my object is at 1000th position, then I will have to do 1000 comparisons to get the intended object. Is there a more effective way with less number of comparisons as I have 67000 such objects currently.

Comment: pickle has basically nothing to do with this. You stored your objects in a list (or some other sequence), which doesn't support efficient lookup by key. The fact that you pickled and unpickled the list doesn't matter. If you want efficient lookup by key, make a dict.

Comment: After your suggestion, this question seems to be improperly thought about. Thank you for the suggestion. I am not sure about the forum guidelines, should I leave the question as it is or take it down.